# Why is my code for finding number of trailing zeros in a factorial returning garbage value

Tags: c++, math, factorial

I want to find the number of trailing zeros in a factorial, but my code is returning garbage values.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
   long int n;
   cin>>n;
   int z=0;
   while(n>0)
   {
      n=n/5;
      n=z+n;
      z=n;
   }
   return z;
}
```

Comment: If you start with `n==5`, your code enters infinite loop. Off the top of my head, I think you just need `n /= 5; z += n;` inside the loop.

Comment: [Working for me](http://rextester.com/ZFJQK47249)

Comment: @BhavyaBhatia For what inputs are you getting a garbage output?  What is that output?  What output do you expect?

Comment: I cant understand how you came with the 5 value to find the number of trailing zeros?

Comment: Whwnever there is a zero in the factorial means there has to be 5 and 2 present in it.So we need to find pairs of two and five for a zero.
In this logic I find out the maximum powers of 5 that will pair up with 2 to form a zero. 60/5=12 12/5=2 2/5 =0 ....No of traling zeros will be 12+2+0 = 14
Now take any value like 60...to find no. if zeros divide it by 5 and continue this till your quotient becomes zero...

Comment: Igor Tandetnik thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your code as follows: Your input is `n` and you want to calculate how many trailing zeros `n!` has. In this case your `while` loop has to look the following way:

```
while(n > 0)
{
    n = n / 5;
    z = z + n;
}

// After running the loop, directly output the result.
cout << "z: " << z;
```

This gives me 249 trailing zeroes in the expansion of 1000!
And 1151 trailing zeroes for 4617!

According to [this page](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm) that should be correct.